# Error from Vuforia sample project

Tags: android-ndk, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to ndk development and I am trying to build an application for augmented reality. For that I am referring to Vuforia's sample projects, and then I will implement my application by making some changes.

My problem is that I cannot build the path for the library. I am new to Vuforia so I do not know how to do it properly. I have searched a lot for help and I am also trying to find instructions on the original site.

Here is the link for [Step 3](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-3-compiling-running-vuforia-sample-app).

Can anybody please explain to me how I can build the Image Targets shared library?

Currently I get this error:

> The library libQCAR.so could not be loaded The library
>
> libUserDefinedTargets.so could not be loaded

Comment: What OS are you developing on (e.g. Mac, Windows, Linux)? Have you built the native code by calling ndk-build, or does this error occur after that?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific in your question, as this step 3 is rather long... where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: look at my solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334041/using-android-studio-with-vuforia